# Drools KieScanner cannot fetch SNAPSHOT version automatically！

Tags: maven, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

I want to integrate the drools workbench 6.5.0.Final with my application.
the code are as follows:

```
 private static void test() throws InterruptedException {
        KieServices kServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        ReleaseId releaseId = kServices.newReleaseId("com.risk", "core-engine-test", "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT");
        kContainer = kServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);

        KieScanner kScanner = kServices.newKieScanner(kContainer);
        kScanner.start(10000L);

        Person p = new Person("郭芙蓉", 8);
        System.out.println("orig p1 : " + p);
        while (true) {
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           KieSession ksession = kContainer.newKieSession("testSession");
                ksession.insert(p);
                ksession.fireAllRules();
                System.out.println("after p1 : " + p);
                ksession.dispose();
            }
  }
```

This below is my settings.xml used by own application.

```
  <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <url>http://10.240.132.81:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

I was install and deploy kjar into my nexus repository.When I was start app at the first time, it will write a tracking file named "resolver-status.properties", and this file record some timstamp , so local server don't fetch newer jar any more which is newer in nexus-server.I got such logs:

```
05-10 15:59:48.657 Not in OSGi: using plexus based maven parser
05-10 15:59:50.168 Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/username/.m2/repository
05-10 15:59:50.175 Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/username/.m2/repository
05-10 15:59:50.231 Using mirror nexus (http://10.240.132.81:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
05-10 15:59:50.262 Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/username/.m2/repository
05-10 15:59:50.277 KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT was not in cache, checking classpath
05-10 15:59:50.277 KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT was not in cache, checking maven repository
05-10 15:59:50.288 Skipped remote request for com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
05-10 15:59:50.588 Skipped remote request for com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
05-10 15:59:50.588 Skipped remote request for com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
05-10 15:59:50.589 Skipped remote request for com.risk:core-engine-test:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
05-10 15:59:50.608 Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=18, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=10}
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: every time I delete "maven-metadata-nexus.xml" , it will download the latest version jar .

Answer (score 0):

At the moment LATEST works pretty well provided that you always use fixed versions. Conversely if you try to use it with SNAPSHOTs it is indeed broken and it is impossible to make it work.
As per the mail chain[1], the answer has been just that "LATEST is broken by design". [1] However it is also stated on the Maven documentation that "For the sake of reproducible builds, Maven 3.x no longer supports usage of these metaversions". [2]

[1] https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aether-users/msg00529.html
[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution